# Unity async task can't be called outside of main thread?

Tags: unity-game-engine, async-await

I need to convert a `.txt` file called `TheFile` to a `dictionary` called `theFileDictionary` and then save it to a **binary file**.
I am doing this with the following class `FileHandler`:

```
public class FileHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TextAsset theFile;
    FileStream file;

    public async Task LoadTheFileIntoBinaryFile()
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new();
        file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/foods.txt");
        /*line 33, error gets called*/ await Task.Run(() => { formatter.Serialize(file, LoadTheFileIntoDictionary()); } );
        file.Close();
    }

    Dictionary<string, string[]> LoadTheFileIntoDictionary()
    {
        /*line 39, error occurs*/Dictionary<string, string[]> theFileDictionary =
                theFile
                .text
                .Split('\n')
                .Select(x => x.Split('\t'))
                .ToDictionary(x => x[ApplicationInfo.GetLanguageIndex()].Replace("-", " "));

        return blsDictionary;
    }
}
```

When starting `LoadTheFileIntoBinaryFile()` I get this **error**:

> UnityException: get_bytes can only be called from the main thread.
> Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
> Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
> UnityEngine.TextAsset.get_text () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/TextAsset.cs:23)
> FileHandler.LoadTheFileIntoDictionary () (at Assets/Scripts/Daten/FileHandler.cs:39)
> FileHandler+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0 () (at Assets/Scripts/Daten/FileHandler.cs:33)
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () (at :0)
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () (at :0)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

From what the error says it seems to be that the `Dictionary` has to be initialised in `Awake()` or `Start()`. When I do that it *kinda* works but I don't need the method in `Start()`, I need it sometimes later (and I still need it to load **asynchronously**)...

I tried declaring and implementing the `Dictionary<string, string[]>` in `Start()` but with no change in result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error means you at least have to get `theFile.text` in the main thread. If `LoadTheFileIntoBinaryFile` is called from the main thread, you can pass `theFile.text` as an argument.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Your operation is I/O-bound **not** CPU-bound so you should be performing the reading of the file **foods.txt** asynchonously via `await File.ReadAllTextAsync()`.  `Task.Run` is for CPU-bound operations so you don't want to be reading files in that as it's a waste of a thread.  Now you could use the latter for your conversion but really, we are talking about games here and you should have done all of that along with TGA, PNG, WAV conversion _ahead of time_ rather than during gameplay.  For advanced operations use the Unity Job System.

Comment: @MickyD if you mean line 33, I am not reading the file, I am writing it. Where do you intent to put `await File.ReadAllTextAsync`?

Comment: Your code is rather confusing TBH.  I can see you are _**creating a file and writing to it**_ using a method called **_Load_** `TheFileIntoBinaryFile`.  Regardless, you should be using async I/O rather than `Task.Run`.